# How to Copy Folders and Files to a Repo in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

I would like to copy all files and folders from one Repo to another.

For example in the image there is a folder called root4adf with a number of sub-folders.

[image]

I would like to copy all the folder root4adf and sub-folders to a new folder called uploadfolder.

[image]

I attempted this by downloading the root4adf as a zip file in the hope that if I uploaded the zip the process would upload the folders and files from the zip file, but it didn't. And it doesn't appear to be possible to upload folders and files to another folder.. unless you upload individual files.